# when I print sum , it prints Nan in xsl

Tags: xslt

I was trying to print sum but it prints sum of each value. I want to get the total sum. How to use a global variable in xsl

as an example to get the sum , simply we can write `sum = sum + value;` value is what we get new and sum is already existing value. what I notice is it always get overwrite in xsl.

here is the code I used

```
<xsl:template match="Top">
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 10">


    <xsl:variable name="items"
             select="/TopHoldings/TopHoldingsEntry
             [@Type='Company Name||Co||Se||F Weight (%)||Benchmark weight (%)']
             [@Date='8/31/2011']" />

    <xsl:variable name="totalMarks" 
         select="format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#') + 
                 format-number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10),'#.#')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$totalMarks" />

  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

where I have done wrong?
xml code

```
<TopHoldings Currency="xxx">
          <TopHoldingsEntry Type="CName||C||S||Fund Weight (%)||Benchmark weight (%)" Value="Ab||U||||1.2170000000000||" Date="8/31/2011" />
          <TopHoldingsEntry Type="CName||C||S||Fund Weight (%)||Benchmark weight (%)" Value="Acc||I||||1.2170000000000||" Date="7/31/2011" />
```

Comment: Can you post your input XML?

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0 here?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are thinking of sum=sum+value suggests that you are trying to do this as you would do it in a procedural language, by writing a loop and changing the value of a variable. Well, XSLT isn't a procedural language so you need to think differently.

In XSLT 2.0 this is simply

```
format-number(
   sum(for $x in TopHoldingsEntry/@Type return number(substring-after('||||'))),
   ....)
```

In XSLT 1.0 it's a bit more difficult. I would do it using "sibling recursion":

```
<xsl:template match="TopHoldingsEntry">
  <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]">
         <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total + number(substring-after(....))"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

and then fire the process off with `<xsl:apply-templates select="TopHoldingsEntry[1]"/>`

Comment: following-sibling::*[1] what does this mean?

Comment: It gets the next sibling element after the context node, that is the immediately following element with the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

Do sum before formatting number

```
<xsl:variable name="total">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10))+
       number(substring(substring-after(@Value,'||||'),1,10))"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="totalMarks" select="format-number($total,1,10),'#.#')"/>
```

Comment: without formatting they can not be summed since they are strings.